# Openwhisk and Node-red issue

Tags: node.js, docker, node-red, openwhisk

I am trying to use node-red and openwhisk together so I can invoke openwhisk actions from node-red. I am using node-red-node-openwhisk (https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-red-node-openwhisk) for that.
I am using openwhisk outside of the bluemix locally with vagrant. I am trying to make this work according to this tutorial: 
https://github.com/kpavel/openwhisk-light
but it seems impossible since I am ok until this comand

```
wsk action --apihost http://localhost:3000 invoke owl-test -r -p mykey myval
```

that I get this:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 4767018,
        "error": "The supplied authentication is invalid"
    },
    "message": "GET https://openwhisk.ng.bluemix.net/api/v1/namespaces/_/actions/owl-test Returned HTTP 401 (Unauthorized) --> \"The supplied authentication is invalid\"",
    "name": "OpenWhiskError",
    "statusCode": 401
}
```

Also I cannot set the openwhisk node to work on my node-red environment because whatever apihost I am using I am getting errors.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

There might be, or have been, a bug with setting the API host via a CLI parameter. It may also be necessary to run this before running your `wsk action` command:

```
wsk property set --apihost http://localhost:3000
```

https://github.com/apache/incubator-openwhisk-cli/issues/131